# How can I display the list price field in product page?

Tags: nodes, commerce

I am new to commerce Kickstart. I can add the list price field in hats content types. But i can't to show the list price field in product page. I don't want to show the SKU field in product page.In node--product-type.tpl.php

.. But it doesn't work it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it much be easier to add a '*product reference*' to your product type when you define the '*content type*'. and simply the '*Product: Price*' field will add to your '*manage display*' in that '*content type*' 
if the price doesn't show up, Modify the settings for the price field on the product type "manage display" configuration.